# All my slash commands duplicated? I changed to global and all my slash commands have duplicated and I'm not sure what I should do

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm not sure what code files I should include so tell me what code files you need. I am on a 10 hour code session it's 5 am and I am not sure what I'm doing really. So be nice.

````
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token, clientId, guildId } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Reloading of global application (/) commands...');
        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Reloading of gloabl application (/) commands successful!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    
})();```
````

Answer (score 0):

When you say you changed to global do you mean you changed the commands from guild specific to global?
If this is the case then I imagine you're seeing commands that are guild based and as well as commands that are global.

I don't think setting the commands to global removes the pre-existing guild ones.

(Side note: I would have added a comment but SO doesnt let me because I have low rep :) )